# SSRS: How to filter for some values or when is NOT equal to some value?

Tags: reporting-services

i have a report with a combo box to allow users to filter for some value.
But, i need also to filter when is not equal to a particular value.
How can i do this in reporting-services ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second combo box that allows users to select Excluded items. Then your query can use both of these parameters:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   myTable
WHERE
   myTable.Name IN ( @IncludedNamesParameter )
   AND myTable.Name NOT IN ( @ExcludedParameters )
```